# Hiding column in datagrid depending on conditials

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I need to display or hide one of data grid's column dynamically depending on condition.

As I know column doesn't present in a logical or visual data grid tree, so I decided to replace it to static resource

What I have

**View**
(Hided namespaces for clear)

```
<UserControl Name="UserControl">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Key="ProblemColumn"
                            Visibility="{Binding DataContext.IsDisplayed, Source={x:Reference UserControl}, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="myModels:SomeModel">
                <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding SomeViewModel}">
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate DataType="myModels:AnotherModel">
                                    <Border>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}"
                                                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                   HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
                                    </Border>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ScrollViewer>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding AnotherItems}">
            <DataGrid.Columns >
                <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    ...
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <StaticResource ResourceKey="ProblemColumn"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

**ViewModel**
There just my property where I explicitly set value for hiding column

```
public bool IsDisplayed => false;
```

So now property is binding properly and it returns value, but no any changes on UI, column still present in datagrid and I can see it even though the value of property is set to false.

What can I missed?

Answer (score 1):

You can hide it by removing a certain column in code behind.

```
<Grid Loaded="OnGridLoaded">
    <ScrollViewer>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding AnotherItems}" x:Name="MyDataGrid">
            <DataGrid.Columns >
                <DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="MyColumn">
                    ...
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <StaticResource ResourceKey="ProblemColumn"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Code behind:

```
private void OnGridLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    var vm = (sender as Grid)?.DataContext as FooVm;    
    if ((vm != null)    
    &&  (vm.IsDisplayed == false))    
    {    
        MyDataGrid.Columns.Remove(MyColumn);        
    }    
}
```